# Change inactive page 'Title'

Tags: javascript, highlighting, page-title

I influenced from [StackOverflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).
Here when the page is inactive then number of the new incoming chat messages are displayed in the Page title. When the page is activated the this number is disappeared. How can I implement this concept in my application? I also want to highlight that window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

detecting when it goes inactive can be done with 'window.onblur' (the [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onblur) event)

detecting when it goes active again can be done with 'window.onfocus' (the [onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onfocus) event)

Comment: And if if you want to check "idle" you can add a timer on a field to check if there was anything that was typed in the field or any other event that you find interesting to check.

Comment: But how can I highlight that page title?

Comment: But in any chat pages we can see that if any new message is arrived, the page title is changed and the page is highlighted with some color (in case of Google Chrome page is highlighted with yellow color). You can test it [here](http://bloochat.com/).

Comment: i just tested it and it doesn't highlight my taskbar entry, it only blinks the title. you cant highlight it. you...cant...highlight...the...taskbar....period. cant make it any clearer.