# Change inactive page Title

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031377/change-inactive-page-title). And I know how to do it in a non angular context.
But to learn the framework I made my own chat using Angular.

Since I am just starting out I would like to know what would be the best course of action for this? Using jQuery would work in a controller but that doesn't seem like the right way. Since you would have to remove the listener once the controller has been destroyed.

To be clear here's what I would like to happen:

If the user switches tabs or windows the title of the page get's updated to reflect the 'missed' entries.
Once he comes back the title resets back to another value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We want to help guide you rather than provide the code!

Comment: @Zack Argyle I was going to put exactly the same thing. We need some lights on what have you done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most 'angular' way would be to create a [`directive`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on some element which listens for the events and changes a scope variable.

I would create an API like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" window-active-model="appIsActive">
  <title>{{appIsActive ? 'My Super App' : 'Come back to me!'}}</title>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 This directive can add listeners, and then broadcast through the scope hierarchy model to the controller that has your chat logic.

Comment: I wouldn't use events for this - just add a $watch if you need to know when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jquery version if anyone needs in future

```
$(function() {
// Get page title
var pageTitle = $("title").text();

// Change page title on blur
$(window).blur(function() {
  $("title").text("Don't forget to read this...");
});

// Change page title back on focus
$(window).focus(function() {
  $("title").text(pageTitle);
});
});
```